# Dashboard like meta boxes in my plugin - how to save their position and open/closed state?

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, dashboard

I am trying to mimic the dashboard meta boxes UI in my WP plugin - the small metaboxes. I have already styled them and also the drag & drop feature works as I loaded the following script and style:

```
wp_enqueue_style('dashboard');
wp_enqueue_script('dashboard');
```

However I also would like to save my custom "postboxes" position (order) and also the open/close state.

Any ideas how could this be achieved?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
This is the structure of my postbox:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php echo get_admin_page_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="postbox-container" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="metabox-holder">
            <div class="meta-box-sortables">
                <div class="postbox" id="first">
                    <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br /></div>
                    <h3 class="hndle"><span><?php echo get_admin_page_title(); ?></span></h3>
                    <div class="inside">
                        <p>first</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postbox" id="second">
                    <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br /></div>
                    <h3 class="hndle"><span><?php echo get_admin_page_title(); ?></span></h3>
                    <div class="inside">
                        <p>second</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form style="display:none" method="get" action="">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('closedpostboxes', 'closedpostboxesnonce', false ); ?>
        <?php wp_nonce_field('meta-box-order', 'meta-box-order-nonce', false ); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ordering or closing metaboxes, those actions require nonces, add the following to your code and see if that resolves the problem.

```
<?php wp_nonce_field('closedpostboxes', 'closedpostboxesnonce', false ); ?>
<?php wp_nonce_field('meta-box-order', 'meta-box-order-nonce', false ); ?>
```

**Additional:**

You should add metaboxes to your page using [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and output them using [`do_meta_boxes`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L919) passing in the hook for your plugin page as the first arg. This should at least ensure you have registered and output them in the same way WordPress does, and providing you've also output the appropriate nonces, should work.

If something still isn't working, view source on your problem page(s) and verify the JS files are being output in the correct order(easier still, compare JS inclusions in your page with a core WordPress page that uses metaboxes, make sure your JS includes(enqueues) appear in the same order).

Comment: I tried to add that, but nothing changed. Probably I am missing something else too.I also added wp_enqueue_script('postbox'); as this is probably the ajax script that is solving this saving. I am going to paste there my structure of these boxes below.

Comment: You need to call `do_meta_boxes` as Scribu pointed out.

Comment: Great I got it working now, I was missing the postboxes.add_postbox_toggles( 'mypagename' ); JS code which I find in scribu's plugin, thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, totally forgot about adding the post box toggles JS(been ages since i used meta boxes in a plugin - i really should do it again just as a refresher).

Comment: No problem :) However one weird thing is if I use input radio button in my metabox and drag it then it losts it's checked focus. When I replace it to checkbox or any other field it works well.

Comment: I vaguely remember having similar problems some time ago, can't quite remember what the solution was, but there is one, perhaps someone else here has an idea?

Comment: Managed to dig up a related [Trac Ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16972) and additionally i realised i never did find a solution, but i did post about this problem myself [here](http://www.wptavern.com/forum/plugins-hacks/1955-plugin-theme-leverages-built-media-uploader.html) also.

Answer (score 3):

It probably won't work if you write the HTML by hand.

Better to use `do_metaboxes()`.

I've got it all figured out in my [scbBoxesPage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/scb-framework/) class:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/scb-framework/trunk/scb/BoxesPage.php?rev=339808

Example usage in the [Front-end Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) plugin:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/front-end-editor/trunk/admin.php?rev=362968

I should probably write a proper example plugin that uses all those classes.